# Concatenate variable and string python script

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation, spyder

I am trying to write a Python script in Spyder to deal with several files at the same time.

Actual path is something like:

```
/TestCondition/TestDate-A1.txt
```

I want to control the TestCondition and TestDate only at the beginning.

```
FoldPath = TestCondition
FileName = TestDate
```

I want to do something like:

```
dfA1 = pd.read_csv(FoldPath&'/'Filename&'A1.txt'
dfA2 = pd.read_csv(FoldPath&'/'Filename&'A2.txt'
....
dfA12 = pd.read_csv(FoldPath&'/'Filename&'A12.txt'

#Code with Pandas and Numpy...
```

How do I concatenate the variable names FoldPath and FileName with the string "A1 to A12" specifically to call out a csv file ? I can't find the correct syntax.

Thanks, 
J-F

***Edit*** Question solved. 
With the knowledge of "import os" and also "os.path.join", I can now find a bunch of examples to do what I intended to do. I know that this question has been asked several times, but with my limited knowledge of Python, and programming in general, I could not find the correct key words. Anyway, thanks again for your quick answers.

Comment: use `os.path.join`

Comment: and the other `os.path` functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `os.path.join` and the `+` to concatenate

```
import os
filepath = os.path.join(FoldPath, FileName + '-A1.txt')
dfA1 = pd.read_csv(filepath ...
```

Answer (score 1):

first..

```
dfA1 = pd.read_csv("/{}/{}-A1.txt".format(FoldPath, Filename)
```

but this code not recommanded.

second.. **use `os.path.join`**

```
dfA1 = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(FoldPath, "{}-A1.txt".format(Filename, ))
```

Comment: Hello. I made it work. Thanks. However, I find that the method proposed below with [...] Filename + '-A1'[...] to be a bit more intuitive.